# Save generated excel file with dialog

Tags: vb.net, excel, winforms, export-to-excel, savefiledialog

I'm generating an xls file from a datatable on a button click.  Right now the path to save the file is hardcoded in the function to generate the file:

```
Function CreateExcelFile(xlFile As String) As Boolean

    Try
        Dim xlRow As Integer = 2
        Dim xlApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        Dim xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
        Dim xlWS = xlApp.Worksheets.Add
        Dim intStr As Integer = 0
        Dim NewFile As String = ""
        Dim strCaption As String = "PSLF Driver Files Records"

        xlFile = Replace(xlFile, "Return Files", "Reports")
        xlFile = Replace(xlFile, "txt", "xlsx")

        xlFile = Replace(xlFile, "_", " ")
        intStr = InStr(xlFile, "Reports")

        xlApp.IgnoreRemoteRequests = True

        xlWS = xlWB.Worksheets(xlApp.ActiveSheet.Name)
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

        xlApp.Sheets.Add()

        Dim xlTopRow As Integer = 2 'First Row to enter data

        xlApp.Sheets.Add()

        xlApp.Sheets(1).Name = strCaption
        xlApp.Sheets(1).Select()

        'Store datatable in 2-dimensional array
        Dim arrExcel(frm_Records.BindingSource1.DataSource.Rows.Count, frm_Records.BindingSource1.DataSource.Columns.Count - 1) As String

        'Write header row to array
        arrExcel(0, 0) = "SSN"
        arrExcel(0, 1) = "CREATE_DATE"
        arrExcel(0, 2) = "SERVICER_CODE"
        arrExcel(0, 3) = "STATUS"
        arrExcel(0, 4) = "DRIVER_FILE_OUT"
        arrExcel(0, 5) = "LAST_UPDATE_USER"
        arrExcel(0, 6) = "LAST_UPDATE_DATE"
        arrExcel(0, 7) = "CREATE_USER"

        'Copy rows from datatable to array
        xlRow = 1
        For Each dr As DataRow In frm_Records.BindingSource1.DataSource.Rows
            arrExcel(xlRow, 0) = dr("SSN")
            arrExcel(xlRow, 1) = dr("CREATE_DATE")
            arrExcel(xlRow, 2) = dr("SERVICER_CODE")
            arrExcel(xlRow, 3) = dr("STATUS")
            If IsDBNull(dr("DRIVER_FILE_OUT")) Then
                arrExcel(xlRow, 4) = ""
            Else
                arrExcel(xlRow, 4) = dr("DRIVER_FILE_OUT")
            End If
            arrExcel(xlRow, 5) = dr("LAST_UPDATE_USER")
            arrExcel(xlRow, 6) = dr("LAST_UPDATE_DATE")
            arrExcel(xlRow, 7) = dr("CREATE_USER")
            xlRow += 1
        Next

        'Set up range
        Dim c1 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range = xlApp.Range("A1") 'Top left of data
        Dim c2 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range = xlApp.Range("T" & frm_Records.BindingSource1.DataSource.Rows.Count - 1 + xlTopRow) 'Bottom right of data
        Dim xlRange As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range = xlApp.Range(c1, c2)

        xlRange.Value = arrExcel 'Write array to range in Excel

        xlWB.ActiveSheet.Range("A:T").Columns.Autofit()
        xlWB.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:T1").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 153)
        xlWB.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:T1").Font.Bold = True

        With xlApp.ActiveWindow
            .SplitColumn = 0
            .SplitRow = 1
        End With

        xlApp.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

        Dim strSheet As String

        For Each Sht In xlWB.Worksheets
            If Sht.name Like "*Sheet*" Then
                strSheet = Sht.name
                xlApp.Sheets(strSheet).delete()
            End If
        Next

        xlApp.IgnoreRemoteRequests = False

        xlWB.SaveAs(xlFile)

        xlWB.Close()

        Dim xlHWND As Integer = xlApp.Hwnd
        'this will have the process ID after call to GetWindowThreadProcessId
        Dim ProcIdXL As Integer = 0
        'get the process ID
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(xlHWND, ProcIdXL)
        'get the process
        Dim xproc As Process = Process.GetProcessById(ProcIdXL)

        xlApp.Quit()

        'Release
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp)



        'set to nothing
        xlApp = Nothing

        'kill it with glee
        If Not xproc.HasExited Then
            xproc.Kill()
        End If


    Catch ex As Exception
        WP.WAPC_RUNSCRIPT_ERROR_FILE(WP.argScriptName, "Error Writing to Excel Report: " & ex.Message)
        Return False
    End Try
    Return True
End Function
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Function GetWindowThreadProcessId(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, _
                      ByRef lpdwProcessId As Integer) As Integer
End Function
#End Region
```

What I want to do is upon completion of the creation of the Excel file, I want to give the user the option of where to save the newly created file.  I'm new at 
Winforms and am not sure how to do this.

What is the best way to enable the user to choose where to saved the file?

Update:
Working code after @Claudius' answer.

```
Private Sub btnRecExport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
btnRecExport.Click 
Dim file As String = "I:\PSLFRecords.xlsx" 
CreateExcelFile(file) 
Dim sfdRecords As New SaveFileDialog() 
sfdRecords.Filter = "Excel File|*.xls" 
sfdRecords.Title = "Save PSLF Driver Records" 
sfdRecords.ShowDialog() 
If sfdRecords.FileName <> "" Then 
xlWB.SaveAs(sfdRecords.FileName) 
fs.Close() 
End If 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename(v=vs.110).aspx) edited to your needs:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
   ' Displays a SaveFileDialog so the user can save the Image
   ' assigned to Button2.
   Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()
   saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel File|*.xls
   saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save an Excel File"
   saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

   ' If the file name is not an empty string open it for saving.
   If saveFileDialog1.FileName <> "" Then
       xlWB.SaveAs(saveFileDialog1.FileName)
       fs.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Here is my button click event with the additional code you wrote above,

Private Sub btnRecExport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRecExport.Click Dim file As String = "I:\PSLFRecords.xlsx"
        CreateExcelFile(file)
        Dim sfdRecords As New SaveFileDialog()
        sfdRecords.Filter = "Excel File|*.xls"
        sfdRecords.Title = "Save PSLF Driver Records"
        sfdRecords.ShowDialog()

        If sfdRecords.FileName <> "" Then
            xlWB.SaveAs(sfdRecords.FileName)
            fs.Close()
        End If
       End Sub

Comment: no no no, dont post code in a comment, edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

All you'd actually need is just a new instance of the [FolderBrowserDialog Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1), that will return to you the path the user selected. All the information you need is already present in the documentation.